# javascript function fails sometimes onchange

Tags: function, onchange

So I have this web page code, which works (sort of) in Firefox, but only the select works in IE8. To make it sort of work in Firefox the alert(`null`) has to be there or it won't go to the `href` given when the `myloc == "MySrch"`. I don't get any feedback errors, which is really confusing.

```
SqlStr = "Select DISTINCT Unit From Employee Where PhoneBook = 1 Order by Unit;"
Set UniNme = Connection.Execute(SqlStr)
Response.Write "<select id='Unit' onChange='Change(this.id)'>"
Response.Write "<option value=''>Choose Unit</option><br>"
Response.Write "<option value='Everyone'>Everyone</option><br>"
Do While Not UniNme.EOF
Response.Write "<option value='"&UniNme("Unit")&"'>"&UniNme("Unit")&"</option><br>"
UniNme.MoveNext
Loop
Response.Write "</select><br>"

Response.Write "Name Search: <input type='text' id='MySrch' onChange='Change(this.id)'>"
```

The javascript function is

```
function Change(myloc) {
if (myloc == "Unit") {
var myindex = document.getElementById(myloc).selectedIndex;
myvalue = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[myindex].value;
} else {
var myvalue = document.getElementById(myloc).value;
}

document.cookie = "Temp1="+escape(myloc);
document.cookie = "Temp2="+escape(myvalue);

document.location.href="AEmployees.asp?action=Change";

alert(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the scope of myvalue variable. it has local visibility here

```
else {
var myvalue = document.getElementById(myloc).value;
}
```

it may not cause the issue but it's potentially dangerous code